# SharePoint Designer 2007 Data Source setting some column to be edit-able

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, libraries, aspx

May I know what configuration should we set in order for certain column to be edit-able (and some column not edit-able) for a Data Source in a SharePoint Designer 2007? The column that to be set not edit-able are to be display and should not hide from the end-user.

Details:
Inside the Office SharePoint Designer 2007 (for SharePoint Server 2007), there is a Data Source Library that shows SharePoint Lists, Libraries, Database Connection and so on. If we drag a SharePoint List called 'Inventory' from the Data Source Library window into a custom aspx file, it will display a table showing data inside the List. If we select the 'Data View properties' and under the 'Editing' tab, it provide us 3 checkbox - one for edit item, one for delete item and one for insert item. Suppose that the 'Inventory' contain 5 column, all column must be display and the first 2 column cannot be editable. The rest of the column must be editable.

"What Data Source that I mean" reference: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-as-a-data-source-HA010117437.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is for a custom edit form of some sort right?

When you create the form after associating a datasource, you can change the field properties to show as Text or a Label which outputs the current value of the item.  Just click the field value in the design pane and click the little chevron.  This is where you can change the field output.

This allows you to specify fields that cannot be changed while retaining other editable fields in your editform.  If I've misunderstood, let me know.

Comment: actually I mean is something like the following in this link - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-as-a-data-source-HA010117437.aspx. From what I know, a sqldatasource can set boundfield to read-only but I could not find that in a datasource.